# JsonReader returns only first result

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get the `"name"` 's from the Json file so I have a list of `"Group A"`, `"Group B"`, ... But it returns only `"Group A"`

```
    private void LoadFromJSON() {

    try {

        //JSON LOCAL
        InputStream input = null;
        try{
            input = c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fifa_world_cup_2014);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            String readerName = ""; 
            String name = "";

                reader.beginArray();
                reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                readerName = reader.nextName();
                if (readerName.equals("name")) {
                     name = reader.nextString();
                   } else {
                     reader.skipValue();
                   }
                Group g = new Group();
                g.setName(name);
                GroupDao gDAO = new GroupDao(activity);
                gDAO.open();
                gDAO.createGroup(g);
                gDAO.close();

            }
                reader.endObject(); 
                reader.endArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

`Json` file:

```
[
{
  "name" : "Group A", 
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "Brazil",
      "flag": "brazil"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cameroon",
      "flag": "cameroon"
    }
  ],
  "matches": [
    {
      "timestamp": "12 June 2014 17:00",
      "team 1": "Brazil",
      "team 2": "Croatia",
      "match": 1
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "18 June 2014 19:00",
      "team 1": "Cameroon",
      "team 2": "Croatia",
      "match": 18
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "23 June 2014 17:00",
      "team 1": "Croatia",
      "team 2": "Mexico",
      "match": 34
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Group B", 
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "Spain",
      "flag": "spain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Netherlands",
      "flag": "netherlands"
    },
    {
      "name": "Australia",
      "flag": "australia"
    }
  ],
  "matches": [
    {
      "timestamp": "13 June 2014 16:00",
      "team 1": "Spain",
      "team 2": "Netherlands",
      "match": 3
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "23 June 2014 13:00",
      "team 1": "Netherlands",
      "team 2": "Chile",
      "match": 36
    }
  ]
}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , At the last line of json string change `}}]` to `}]`

Second , your code for parsing json is wrong , Use this code instead

```
private void LoadFromJSON() {

try {

    //JSON LOCAL
    InputStream input = null;
    try{
        input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fifa_world_cup_2014);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        String readerName = ""; 
        String name = "";

        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.beginObject();
            while(reader.hasNext())
            {
                readerName = reader.nextName();
                if (readerName.equals("name")) {
                     name = reader.nextString();
                     Group g = new Group();
                     g.setName(name);
                     GroupDao gDAO = new GroupDao(activity);
                     gDAO.open();
                     gDAO.createGroup(g);
                     gDAO.close();
                } else {
                     reader.skipValue();
                }

            }
            reader.endObject();
        }
        reader.endArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}catch(Exception e){

}
}
```

I tested the code , works fine and parse both Group A and Group B.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine while debugging. It stops when it reads "Group B" at gDao.createGroup(g) as the primary key (database) must be unique. They're both '0' so it throws an error :/ But that's a totally different problem, your solution works if I didn't have the error